# Saving Auth token in localStorage (React + ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, electron

After login functionality, I am saving my auth token in browser's localStorage, so that i can authenticate each action fired to the server. After login i have to refresh my browser to retrieve my token, since root component is not rerendered. is there any way to rerender index.js? I am building an electron app, so browser refresh is not an option.

**in index.js**

```
const AUTH_TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('user')

if(AUTH_TOKEN){
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
  store.dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATED});
}
```

but this will only get rendered only the first time app loads. Store and routes are defined inside. So after login auth token will be saved in localstorage but its not updated in app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what i did

**In Auth action**

```
            localStorage.setItem('user', response.data.auth_token);
            localStorage.setItem('name', response.data.user.name);
            localStorage.setItem('email', response.data.user.email);
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.auth_token;
            dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATED });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the axios authorization header after saving the auth token.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage token like there, its updated on token expire, token change

```
const watchToken = (delay) => {
      return setTimeout(() => {
        myApi.getToken().then(res => {
          if (res.token) {
            store.dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATED })
          } else {
            store.dispatch({ type: NOT_AUTHENTICATED })
          }
        })
      }, delay);
    }

    class App extends Component {
      tokenManager;

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isReady: false
        };
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.tokenManager = watchToken(20000)
      }

      componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextProps.TOKEN !== this.props.TOKEN) {
          this.tokenManager = watchToken(20000);
        }
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.tokenManager.clearTimeout();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```